# tibble and dataframe, function

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
mat_iris <- as.matrix(iris)

tidyr::as_tibble(mat_iris)
tibble::as_tibble(mat_iris)


tidyr background work tibble ?

dplyr::tbl_df(mat_iris)
dplyr::as_data_frame(mat_iris)
```

What's the difference two ?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/tbl_df
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.0/topics/as_data_frame

Comment: Are you asking for what is the difference between a tibble and a data.frame? Or are you asking about the dffference between the various `tidyverse` methods to convert things into tibbles?

Comment: 1st:I ask tidyr has as_tibble? or tibble has as_tibble?

2nd:I want to ask tbl_df and as_data_frame are same transforming,(matrix to dataframe)
there have different roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of your confusion is about the difference between tibbles and data.frames. Tibbles are a special class of data.frame. Tibbles add increased functionality to data.frames, like improved printing by providing the data type in each column when printed. Tibbles also default to printing only the first ten rows, and make some adjustments based on the width of the output console.

Compare what happens in the console when you print `mtcars` versus `tibble(mtcars)`.

Another difference is that tibbles are stricter when you ask them to do something, like subsetting. Compare what happens when you ask `mtcars` for a column that does not exist.

```
# data.frame
mtcars$bounce
NULL

# tibble
tibble(mtcars)$bounce
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `bounce`.
```

The tibble kindly informs you that you asked for something that does not exist.

One last difference is that tibbles can have columns where the entries are not values, but vectors, lists, and other data.frames.

Read more about the difference at [this blog entry](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/#:%7E:text=Tibbles%20vs%20data%20frames,to%20work%20with%20large%20data.).

As for the specific functions: `as_tibble()` converts something to a tibble. The functions `tibble::as_tibble`, `dplyr::as_tibble` and `tidyr::as_tibble` are all the same function. The function is from the `tibble` package, but it has been exported to `dplyr` and `tidyr` so you can use it in those packages without needing to load `tibble`.

The `tbl_df()` function from `dplyr` is a legacy function for `dplyr` to use to coerce things into tibbles. The documentation page for `tbl_df()` indicated that this function has been superseded by `as_tibble()`. You should use `as_tibble()`, but `tbl_df()` remains in the package for reverse compatibility.

The `as_data_frame()` function is a deprecated function for columnwise construction of tibbles that has been replaced by `as_tibble()`. I am using `tibble v 3.0.3` and `dplyr v 1.0.1`, and I get prevented from trying use `as_data_frame()` with a warning message to to use `as_tibble()` instead.

Comment: Your answers have answered all of my questions. Thank you !